# Looking up the value of cells above a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

thank you for reading this.

I have a row containing a list of text.

APA

VEN

GRAB

I have a table containing either I or Super. Below the table, there are corresponding text such as APA, VEN, GRAB or blank formula cells.

I want to get the cells above a non-blank formula cell. For example, in the row APA, VEN, GRAB that I have..

I want APA to return the value of 5 cells above it. I know how to return one value above it (i.e. Super), but I am not sure how to get the 4 cells above Super.

APA I I I I Super

VEN

GRAB

Edit: =INDEX(AZ53:BA57,MATCH(BA58,BA53:BA57,0)-1,0) This is what I tried to return the cell above APA. I am trying to figure out how to return the 5 cells above APA.

I know I can enter formula to each cell. I wanted to do it in a formula if possible. Thank you again.

```
=INDEX(AZ53:BZ57,MATCH(BA58,BA53:BA57,0)-2,0)
=INDEX(AZ53:BZ57,MATCH(BA58,BA53:BA57,0)-3,0)
=INDEX(AZ53:BZ57,MATCH(BA58,BA53:BA57,0)-4,0)
=INDEX(AZ53:BZ57,MATCH(BA58,BA53:BA57,0)-5,0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxMSU.png)

Comment: how would you do it for 1 row above?

Comment: *I want....*" is not really a good question. Let us know what you attempted and where you are stuck. Narrow your question down please.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I edited to show what I attempted.

Comment: Please include a screenshot within the question or construct a table to make your Q much clearer - I'm having difficulty visualising whilst paying attention to whether you're referring to a row or column, and where the various tables are positioned in relation to one another.  Ta

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## Answer based on inital question

Cell **F10** contains the following formula `=INDEX(F:F;ROW(F$10)+INDEX($C$2:$C$4;MATCH(F$9;$B$2:$B$4;0))-1)` which has then be copied to **G10** and **I10**.

I used the area **B2:C4** to define the negative offsets for your *non-blank content*. As the field in which I display the result of the formula is one row below your *non-blank content* I added an additional **-1** to the formula.

*The grey numbers and the yellow highlights have been used to quickly validate the outcome.*

## Update based on questioner's comment

According to your instructions, source ranges (purple) would intersect with target ranges (blue), see cells with red border.

[image]

As it is not possible to put both a formula and a value into the same cell, I assumed that you wanted to explain independently

- how the target should be structured and
- how the source should be structured.

Hence, it looks like you are looking for a formula that transposes your values from columns into rows.

[image]

In the above image, the highlighted cells contain the following formula (example for cell S14):

```
=OFFSET(source_anchor,COLUMN(S14)-COLUMN(target_anchor),ROW(S14)-ROW(target_anchor))
```

**source_anchor** refers to cell **Q3**

**target_anchor** refers to cell **R13**

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for. If it is not the case, then please provide a mock-up.

Comment: Hi, thank you Qualia. So in Cell C2:H2, next to APA (cell B2), I am looking to try to pull in F2:F7 in your example using a single formula.

Another example is for Cell C4:H4, I am trying to pull H2:H7. 

If possible, I can just drag C2 down using a formula, and it will refer to column B, and search for the corresponding cells above row 9. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @user16233760: did you look at the update? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Qualia, it's not, but thank you very much, I really appreciate it. I am attaching a screenshot in my original image. What I am trying to do is to find a way that if I drag the formula in a row (e.g. from Row 1 to 10), the column will fill out automatically. The reason is that I have thousands of column, and it takes a lot of work to do it for multiple sheets.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not get it. Could you provide a template with sample data, e.g. one tab showing the initial table and another one showing the desired result?